# How to convert a excel formula with quotes and commas to vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I was wondering how to get a excel formula I have to work in VBA?

```
Sheet1.Range("AF9").Formula = "=IF(AND(AA9<>"",AB9<>"",AC9<>"",AD9="",AE9=""),""""&AA9&""","&""""&AB9&""","&""""&AC9&""","&""""","&"""""","")"
```

That is my current vba code (not working) ...

This is what the formula is in the excel sheet itself...

```
=IF(AND(AA9<>"",AB9<>"",AC9<>"",AD9="",AE9=""),""""&AA9&""","&""""&AB9&""","&""""&AC9&""","&""""","&"""""","")
```

I am not finding the linked answer helpful. I understand the double quotes part but I'm not understanding why the commas are causing an error.

Comment: that article suggested is not the same question as i am having issues with the commas and quotes

Comment: I keep removing the unnecessary parts of your question.  We do not use platitudes and fluff in the question, or answers for that matter.  The `,` are not the problem.  Every `"` in the working excel formula needs to be doubled `""` to work.  That is what the answer to the duplicate is saying.

Comment: Here: `Sheet1.Range("AF9").Formula = "=IF(AND(AA9<>"""",AB9<>"""",AC9<>"""",AD9="""",AE9=""""),""""""""&AA9&"""""",""&""""""""&AB9&"""""",""&""""""""&AC9&"""""",""&"""""""""",""&"""""""""""","""")"`

Comment: That worked great! sorry i am very new to these types of websites and apologize for using the forum incorrectly Thank you!